# How to create category and sub category programmatically in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

I am trying to create categories and sub-categories pro-grammatically in Shopware 6.

I looked at the entity class of `Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryEntity` but i'm not sure that whether this class will work or not?  I do not want to assign any products.

Does any one know how to create categories in the Shopware 6?

Answer (score 2):

Creating categories is like creating any other entity through their repository. You can get the category repository from `$this->container->get('category.repository')` and then simply call the `->create` method on the repository object.

You will have to pass the `data` array to it as the first argument and a `context` as the second argument. What data you need to pass in the array you can check out the `CategoryEntity` class (which you have correctly identified already).